# Problemas para enviar formulario con submit php

Tags: php, html, botón, submit

Hola soy nuevo en esto necesito ayuda..
Tengo un formulario donde ingreso los datos pero al dar click en el boton no me ejecuta ninguna accion.. Ayudemen porfavor

Este es el codigo

```
<?php
require_once "../Modelo/ModeloUsuario.php";
ob_start();
?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
       ESPAMMFL-EP
        <small>ADMIN</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="Index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Usuario</a></li>
        <li class="active">Panel Principal</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

   <div class="box box-primary">
     <div class="box-header with-border">
       <h3 class="box-title">Registro de Usuario</h3>
    </div>

    <form action="../Modelo/ModeloUsuario.php" method="POST" id="frmUsuario" name="frmUsuario">          
      <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
      <div class="box-body">

        <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblnombreu">Nombre:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtnombreu" name="txtnombreu" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre..." required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblapellidou">Apellidos:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtapellidou" name="txtapellidou" placeholder="Ingrese sus Apellidos...">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblnacionalidadu">Nacionalidad:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="cmbnacionalidad" name="cmbnacionalidad">
                    <option value="Ecuatoriana">Ecuatoriana</option>
                    <option value="Peruana">Peruana</option>
                    <option value="Colombiana">Colombiana</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblcedulau">Cédula:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcedulau" name="txtcedulau" placeholder="Ingrese su Cedula...">
                </div>


                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblpasaporteu">Pasaporte:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtpasaporteu" name="txtpasaporteu" placeholder="Ingrese su Pasaporte">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblemailu">Teléfono:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txttelefonou" name="txttelefonou" placeholder="Ingrese su Telefono...">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblemailu">Correo:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtemailu" name="txtemailu" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblprofesionu">Profesión:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtprofesionu" name="txtprofesionu" placeholder="Seleccione su profesión">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblusuariou">Nombre de Usuairo:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="txtusuariou" name="txtusuariou" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="lblcontraseñau">Contraseña:</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtcontraseñau" name="txtcontraseñau" placeholder="Contraseña">
                </div>
                <!--<div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                  </label>
                </div>-->
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-body -->

              <div class="box-footer">
                <imput name="btningresaru" id="btningresaru" value="Ingresar" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar
              </div>

              </form>
          </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>

  <?php
  $contenido = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  require_once 'Master.php';
  ?>
```

Comment: Revisa la pregunta ya que no se muestra ningún código.

Comment: Tu `input` **guardar** esta de la siguiente manera `<imput name="btningresaru" id="btningresaru" value="Ingresar" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar` dice **imput** tendria que decir `input` . Aparte no veo en ninguna parte que ese **input** sea de tipo `submit` a menos que lo estés enviando mediante algun script

Comment: te falta tambien el type="button" o type="submit"

Comment: tal como te dicen en los otros comentarios debes de poner al input type="submit" para que lo puedas enviar al archivo que deseas que lo procese en este caso a  "ModeloUsuario.php"